# How to set checkbox value to symfony 'true'?

Tags: jquery, html, symfony

**My code :**

```
 // {{ form_row(form.termsAccept) }} generates #user_termsAccept checkbox field
termsBox.attr("disabled",true);
termsBox.attr("checked",true);
termsBox.val('true'); // OR termsBox.val(1); OR termsBox.val(true); OR termsBox.val(termsBox.prop('checked'));
```

**Problem :** After submit I get 'This value should be true.' error from Symfony despite of fact that visual state of check-box is 'true'. No matter what value I am trying to set, when checking by console.log() the output value is '1' (which is default for symfony check-box).

**Question :** How to set disabled check-box value to "symfony's 'true'" VIA jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

When you build your form (controller), use :

```
$builder->add('termsBox', CheckboxType::class, array(
    'attr' => array(
        'disabled' =>'disabled',
        'checked'  => 'checked',
        'data'     => true,
    ),
));
```

Instead of use jQuery.
Or, in your entity, add a default value to the field's mapping :

```
protected $termsBox = true;
```

Comment: But I wish to change check-box value when some jQuery event is fired, and thats the reason I need to access it via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Disabled inputs will not get processed the alternative would be to set the input to ready only.

Unfortunatly you can't set checkbox to readonly but a workaround would be :

```
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" />
```

This will prevent user clicks so you can get your js manage its state